Checking a database maximum limit and preventing a do while loop from running if maximum value has been reached
This C program is a library database that allows user to add book details to populate a struct and store multiple structs in an array of  a defined maximum value into an external file.
The current problem is that although the value of the defined maximum value is checked, the do while loop continues execution. Ideally, I'm attempting to prevent the user from selecting the option to add book from the menu and return back to the main menu.
After compiliation, the program continues to print "Invalid ISBN". Instead I'm trying to replace this behaviour with "List is full" and return to the main where the user to presented with the main menu.
I've tried removing the do while loop but the functionality fails. I added if statements before the do while  :
    if (*size == MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE){
        printf("List is full\n");
        break;
    }

but again, the program functionality decreases.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*******************************************************************************
 * List preprocessing directives - you may define your own.
*******************************************************************************/

/*Macro to define sizes*/
#define MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE 2
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 50
#define MAX_AUTHOR_SIZE 50

/*******************************************************************************
 * List structs - you may define struct date_time and struct flight only. Each
 * struct definition should have only the fields mentioned in the assignment
 * description.
*******************************************************************************/

/*Structure definition for date*/
typedef struct {
    unsigned int month; /* 1 to 12*/
    unsigned int year;  /* 1950 to 2024*/
} date;

/*Structure definition for a book*/
typedef struct {
    char title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE];
    char author[MAX_AUTHOR_SIZE];
    char isbn[20]; 
    date publication_date;
    char genre[50];
} book_t;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes - do NOT change the given prototypes. However you may
 * define your own functions if required.
*******************************************************************************/
void printMenu(void);

/*Function prototype*/
void addBook(book_t **library, int *size);
void deleteBook(int *size);
void libraryToFile(book_t *library, int size, const char *filename);
void displayLibrary(book_t *library, int *size);
void FileToSerial(book_t *library, int size, const char *filename);

/*******************************************************************************
 * Main
*******************************************************************************/
int main(void){

    book_t *library = NULL;
    const char fileName[] = "database";
    int size = 0;
    int decision;

    do {
        printMenu();
        /*User selection from main menu*/
        printf("Enter your choice>\n");
        if (scanf("%i", &decision) != 1 || decision < 1 || decision > 6){
            printf("Invalid choice.\n");
            /*Clear input buffer*/
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            continue;
        }
        /*Check if the library is full*/
        if (decision == 1 && size == MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE){
            /*printf("List is full\n");*/
            continue;
        }
        switch(decision){
            case 1:
                addBook(&library, &size);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (size == 0){
                    printf("List is empty\n");
                } else {
                    deleteBook(&size);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (size == 0){
                    printf("List is empty\n");
                } else {
                    displayLibrary(library, &size);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (size == 0){
                    printf("List is empty\n");
                } else {
                    libraryToFile(library, size, fileName);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                FileToSerial(library, size, fileName);
                break;
            case 6:
                free(library);
                return 1;
        }
    } while (1);

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * This function prints the initial menu with all instructions on how to use
 * this program.
 * inputs:
 * - none
 * outputs:
 * - none
*******************************************************************************/
void printMenu(void){
    printf("\nLibrary Management System \n"
        "1. Add book\n"
        "2. Delete last book\n"
        "3. Display book list\n"
        "4. Save the book list to the database\n"
        "5. Read the book list from the database\n"
        "6. Exit the program\n");
}

void addBook(book_t **library, int *size){
    if (*size == MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE){
        printf("List is full\n");
        return;
    } 
    if (*library == NULL){
        /*Dynamically allocate memory for an array of structs*/
        *library = (book_t*)malloc(MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE * sizeof(book_t));
        if (*library == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            return;
        }
    } 

    int x;
    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF);

    printf("Title: >");
    scanf(" %15s", (*library)[*size].title); 
    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF);

    printf("Author: >");
    scanf(" %14s", (*library)[*size].author);
    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF);

    /*Check for valid ISBN input*/
    char isbnBuf[12];
    int valid = 0;
    do { 
        if (*size == MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE){
            printf("List is full\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("ISBN: >");
        scanf(" %11s", isbnBuf);
        while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF);

        size_t len = strlen(isbnBuf);
        valid = 1;
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if (isbnBuf[i] < '0' || isbnBuf[i] > '9'){
                valid = 0;
              break; 
            }
        }
        if (len > 11 || !valid){
            printf("Invalid ISBN. ");
        } else {
            strcpy((*library)[*size].isbn, isbnBuf);
            /*Break here if ISBN is valid*/
            break;
        }

    }   while(1);


    /*Note: Passing the address of book->publication_date.month, requires '&'
    *Operator. Providing 'scanf' with the correct argument type 
    *(pointer to an unsigned int (unsigned int *))
    */

    /*Check date validation*/

    printf("Publication_date(month): >");
    scanf("%2u", &(*library)[*size].publication_date.month);

    while ((*library)[*size].publication_date.month < 1 || 
            (*library)[*size].publication_date.month > 12){
        printf("Invalid month. ");
        printf("Publication_date(month): >");
        scanf("%u", &library[*size]->publication_date.month);
        int i;
        while ((i = getchar()) != '\n'){
            i = getchar();
        }

    }

    printf("Publication_date(year): >");
    scanf("%4u", &(*library)[*size].publication_date.year);

    while ((*library)[*size].publication_date.year < 1950 || 
            (*library)[*size].publication_date.year > 2024) {
        printf("Invalid year. ");
        printf("Publication_date(year): >");
        scanf("%u", &(*library)[*size].publication_date.year);
        int i;
        while ((i = getchar()) != '\n'){
            i = getchar();
        }
    }

    printf("Genre: >");
    scanf(" %10s", (*library)[*size].genre); 
    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' && x != EOF);
    

    (*size)++; 
    printf("\n");
    
}

void deleteBook(int *size){
    /*minus 1 from size of library array or p*/
    if(*size == 0){
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    } 
    (*size)--;

}



void libraryToFile(book_t *library, int size, const char *filename){

    if (library == NULL){
        printf("Library is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    /*Opening file in append mode*/
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        return;
    }    
    int i;

    /*Assign each book in the library aray to the book_t and write to file*/
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        book_t book = library[i];
        fprintf(file, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%d%d\t%s\n", book.title, book.author, book.isbn,
        book.publication_date.month, book.publication_date.year, book.genre);
    }
    fclose(file);
    /*printf("Library stored on database.\n");*/
}

void displayLibrary(book_t *library, int *size){

    /*Check if the library pointer is not NULL*/
    if(library == NULL){
        printf("Library is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    
    book_t book;
    if(*size == 0){
        printf("List is empty\n");
    } else {
        printf("Title          Author         ISBN       Pub. Date Genre\n"   
                "----------     ----------     ---------- --------- --------");
        printf("\n");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < *size; i++){
            book = library[i];
            printf("%-10.10s     %-10.10s     %-10s %02u-%4u   %s", book.title, book.author, book.isbn,
                    book.publication_date.month, book.publication_date.year, book.genre);
            printf("\n");
    
         }
    }
}

void FileToSerial(book_t *library, int size, const char *filename){
    /*Check if library pointer is not NULL*/
    if (library == NULL){
        printf("Read error\n"); 
        return;
    }
    /*Open file to read*/
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL){

        /*Read data from the file and print to serial*/
        book_t book;
        int i = 0;
        while (fscanf(file, "%15s %15s %11s %2u%4u %10s\n", book.title, book.author, book.isbn,
                    &book.publication_date.month, &book.publication_date.year, book.genre) != EOF){
            /*Add book to library array*/
            library[i] = book;
            i++;
            if (i >= MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE){
                size = MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE;
                break;
            } else {
                size = i;
            }
        }
            fclose(file);
        } else {
            printf("Read error\n"); 

        }
}


If you can do if (size == 0) { printf("List is empty\n"); ...  for other case options, what stops you from doing if(size >= MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE) { printf("List is full\n"); ... ?

The if (*size == MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE) { ... return; } at the top is sufficient [and necessary]. The same if in the do/while doesn't do anything because *size remains the same until the bottom of the function. The optimizer might even detect this and eliminate the second if because it can never be true.
